# session recovery best practice in Aeron

Tags: java, .net, session, connection, aeron

How to recover a closed session from the client-side in Aeron? Imagine that our Aeron server-side is down and killed, now clients need to have a proper plan to re-connect when the server is available. is there any best practice for this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Aeron you can detect if a Publication or Subscription is connected with the isConnected() method. If you disconnect you need an application strategy to decide how your proceed. Just like you would with TCP, or another communication mechanism, you need to have a recovery protocol for how you re-establish state. This is into the realms of distributed systems design and protocols and not just Aeron.